# pdf of a Product of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I have two independent random variables, $X$ and $Y$, each having a pdf of $1/x^2$, defined on the same interval $1\le x < \infty$. We have to find the joint pdf of $XY$ and $X$, i.e. $f(XY,X)$. For that, I either need $F(XY)$ or $f(XY)$, and that's what I'm having trouble with. Would you just multiply the pdfs together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You know the joint density function of $(X,Y)$  and then using [transformation of random vector](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/160) you can get the desired result.